# All You Need is Kill ending implication

Tags: all-you-need-is-kill

Spoiler:

> At the end of All You Need is Kill Rita says both of them are serving as antennas and so one of them needs to die, so the information can't travel back to the mimics.
>
>  But why was it not a problem before, when Rita won other battles by
>  killing the server/antenna? Wasn't she also an antenna back them?

Comment: No idea how different the book is from the movie, but in the movie, they only ever win battles - never the war, which I think is the point.

Comment: @phantom42 the book is very different on this aspect(and many others)

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a bit hazy on the actual mechanics, but Rita believes that

> the process of killing the nexus will break the loop for the one doing the killing by making them no longer an antenna. From that point onwards, that person will not send the information/memories back in time at the time of their death. However, with there being two of them, if one of them kills the nexus, the other will send the information back in time, "restarting" the loop.

Rita believes this because

> Keiji killed the nexus in one of the loops and the loop immediately restarted, presumably since one of the antennae, Rita was still alive. There's no indication that Rita ever managed to kill all of the antennae and then the nexus on her own; it may be that they only succeeded those last two times because there were two of them. When he kills Rita, slaughters the other mimics, then kills the nexus, time does not loop, so presumably, Rita's theory was true and the loops is now ended.

Comment: @Jorgel: Is there anything I can add to this answer to improve it for you?

Comment: I think at one point she also says she thinks "being an antenna" is something that develops on you - stronger over time - and is related to why the migraines get stronger over time.  (But I don't know why she believes these things.)